# Visual studio 2008 settings get reset on close

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Whenever I close VS 2008. On re-open the customs settings are reset. I cannot successfully import settings from a settings file, as VS wont change when the settings are imported. The only option I  can do is go through and manually change all the settings again and just not closed VS. Anyone experience this before?

Environment 
Windows 7
vs 2008
64 bit intel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Visual Studio starting in the context of your user account?  Anything modified in the shortcut properties?

VS2008 settings are stored in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\...`.  Is there anything unusual about this registry key?

For example, find one of the settings that you might change, such as `General\FileReloadOption`, select it and hit `Edit/Permissions` in the menu.  You should see that your user account has ownership and full control inherited from the CURRENT_USER key (you need to hit advanced to see inheritance and ownership info).

You could try deleting this registry key and letting VS recreate it, but I would make a backup first using the export option.

If that doesn't lead anywhere, I would recommend running [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to watch what Visual Studio is doing in the registry.  If it's trying to write settings somewhere else or failing to write them, that will show up in ProcMon.

edit:

Under the filter settings, add:

- Process Name is devenv.exe
- Event Class is Write
- Category is Registry

I started VS2008, started logging in procmon with those settings, and modified the tools/options/autosave/interval to 6 minutes.  When I closed the options dialog, I immediately saw this:

[image: screenshot]

If you can get the same output, you should be able to see if it's saving settings in an unexpected location, and see the result code from the `RegSetValue` API, which will indicate what the problem is if it's failing.

By the way, I'm also on Win7/64, but I have UAC disabled.  If you're running with UAC you might try disabling it temporarily to see if that has any effect.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but i didn't notice anything extremely unusual from procmon. Mainly because I dont know what is normal, and the amount of data was almost overload level.

Comment: Fixed, it was a bad registry write. I removed the register value it was writing to. Then re-imported and it worked. Thanks!!